# External data column in external list sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In Sharepoint 2010 BCS, how to use external data column which is from external content type-DEPARTMENT in an external list which is creating from external content type-EMPLOYEE. In database scenario DEPARTMENT id is foreign key to Employee table.

Thanks in advance!!